# dynamic path with exec function

Tags: php

I have tu use pdfInfo.exe in my Symfony application.

I did a test function that works with this code :

```
/**
     * @Route("/testPdfNbPages", name="testPdfNbPages")
     *
     */
    public function testPdfNbPagesAction()
    {

        // test récup nombre de pages
        //$cmd = "/path/to/pdfinfo";           // Linux
        //$cmd = "C:\\path\\to\\pdfinfo.exe";  // Windows
        $cmd = "C:\\wamp\\www\\skilbag\\tools\\pdfinfo.exe";  // Windows

        // Parse entire output
        // Surround with double quotes if file name has spaces
        exec("$cmd \"C:\\wamp\\www\\skilbag\\tmp\\test_knpBundle\\test_1504964698.pdf\"", $output);

        // Iterate through lines
        $pagecount = 0;
        foreach($output as $op)
        {
            // Extract the number
            if(preg_match("/Pages:\s*(\d+)/i", $op, $matches) === 1)
            {
                $pagecount = intval($matches[1]);
                break;
            }
        }

        return new Response($pagecount);
    }
```

But in my application, I have to use the exec function with a file whose path will be generated dynamically and I do not know how to do with the slashs.

I have to generate path for Windows and linux.

Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` but you don't need `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` just use `/`.

Comment: Just replace every \ for / and it should be ok.